# Wp-minify doesn't seem to minify my JS code

Tags: plugins, templates, javascript

I've added to the theme (twenty ten) a php template file in which I've written some javascript code.
I then created a new page and set it to use that template.
Then I installed and activated the 'wp-minify' plugin hoping for it to drop the blanks and comments.
But when I look at the page's source code in the browser I see the code regularly.
Your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand WP Minify plugin works on scripts and styles that are included in your page `<head>` tag as external files and not scripts and style that are in the `<body>` tag.

if you are inserting scripts and style in the `<body>` tag manully you should insert it after you minify it and you can use many of the free [**online minify tools**](http://www.google.co.il/search?hl=iw&client=firefox-a&hs=bmW&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&q=js%20minify%20online&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=)

Comment: my code resides in the head tag but is internal. Why is it better to pre-minify the code then using a plugin which will automate things for me?

Comment: I'm not saying its better but its a solution because the plugin works in a way that doesn't work for you obviously, an alternative would be to create your code in an external file and include it (which is a preferred way SEO wise).

Comment: the online minify tools did a better job for me than the plugin so I'm gonna stick with them.
It's a shame though, since the plugin doesn't touch the js code. It only changes the served html. And also, it minifies automatically. With the online tools I have to do it manually after each code change and I have to keep a copy of the code. Still, the result is better.
And thanks for the SEO tip.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's because your js is inline and not a .js file.

Comment: my js is indeed inline, but I can't find in the plugin's documentation a note saying the js should be external to be minified.

Comment: @Ash the documentation doesn't mention it but if you check out the plugin's code you will see just who it works.

Comment: Actually, I now see that it did work on my inline code. It just didn't do a very good job. Only the space line are gone. Comments still left in and no other spaces were removed. I'll do it with one of the online tools.

Comment: Also, If you want to minify external code using wp-minify you should state so in the plugin's advanced settings. I couldn't make it work, though.